# Unity scroll view items are overlapping

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, panel

[image: image link]

Here is my code
  I have made a prefab. the prefab contains a image and button and its text. 
  text height is dynamic as the amount of text increases it will stretch downward.
  As a result items in scroll view are overlapping as shown in the image. 
  i am new to unity please help me.

```cs
     RectTransform rt = (RectTransform)mainScrollContentView.transform;
        foreach (DummyObj dummyObj in objList)
        {
            GameObject playerTextPanel = (GameObject)Instantiate(contentDataPanel);
            playerTextPanel.transform.SetParent(mainScrollContentView.transform);
            playerTextPanel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            playerTextPanel.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            playerTextPanel.transform.Find("Textbtn").GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = dummyObj.Title;
            Image imageView = playerTextPanel.transform.Find("Image").GetComponent<Image>();
            playerTextPanel.transform.Find("Button").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(dummyObj));
            // Retrieving image form URL
            WWW www = new WWW(dummyObj.URL);
            yield return www;
            imageView.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
```

Comment: there is no image attached though

Comment: I have not reputation. so i can not attach image

Comment: Give your suggestion to help me fix this issue or some sample code.

Comment: I have provided image link above.